# why textbutton not go in line with a normal text in a ROW

Tags: flutter

i have a row which has 2 childrens spaceBetween , the first is normal text and the second is textbutton but the textbutton not goes in line with the text why??

```
Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children:[
                                        Text("Instructions:", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontSize: 11),),
                                        TextButton(
                                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                                minimumSize: Size(0, 0),
                                            ),
                                            child: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.grey[600], size: 15,),
                                            onPressed: (){},
                                        )
                                    ]
                                ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Container: 
  height: 20,   // give height as per requirement
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children:[
      Text("Instructions:", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontSize: 11),),
      TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        ),
        child: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.grey[600], size: 15,),
        onPressed: (){},
      )
    ]
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the text "Istructions:" and the TextButton with the Icon are aligned correctly.
But the button is taking a lot of vertical space, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

I suggest you 2 solutions>

You could set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` to the Row.
In that way the text will be vertically aligned with the Button.

Otherwhise you could resize the button to take less height.